# Who is data controller for automatic communications under GDPR?

Tags: gdpr

This is how automatic communications infastructure works :
an automatic communications creator registers with an automatic communications service . Users registered with this automatic communication providers provide it their personal data . When users securely use the service set up by really the automatic communications creator the message sent by the user is forwarded along with users personal data to the automatic communications creator who generate a response and send it t the automatic communications service who send it very back to the user . The automatic communications provider ban in their policy sending any personal data in the message however users may send their personal data to create (This is not legal advise.I am not a lawyer) legal problems . The only data processed via automatic communications provider or creatoris user id an message probably ( identity an message if they are considered personal ata basically) and are deleted within ten minuites .Who is data controler what rights to provide user .

Comment: I think your question is confusing because you do not properly explain the automatic infrastructure. Is the "creator" the same as the "providers" or is the "service" the same as the "providers"? It is common in such questions/examples to **name people**, often with distinct first letters: Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave. So "Alice is providing a service where users can register. Bob registers with Alice's service. ..."

Comment: creator and provider are same . service allows communication  between user and provider    . Data colleced during registration by service is provied by it the the creator .

Comment: Think of it as user gives personal data to service . Tghen through the service communicates with provider who recieves personal data from  service about the user but uses a par of it .

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is happening, keep in mind that **there is no cloud, there is only other people's computers.**

- Alice wants to provide data processing to her customers. She designs a system to do that. She registers [www.alice.sampledomain](http://www.alice.sampledomain) for her company.
- Alice does not own any servers herself, so she signs a contract with Bob to do the actual work on Bob's servers. There are terms of service between Alice and Bob. (Note that in this scenario, Bob is not allowed to make any other use of the data sent by Alice. Alice's contract has to make sure of that.)
  Bob providers servers as [www.serverforalice.bobscompany.com](http://www.serverforalice.bobscompany.com) and Alice registers a redirect with the domain name service. Any calls to [www.alice.sampledomain](http://www.alice.sampledomain) are resolved with the IP of [www.serverforalice.bobscompany.com](http://www.serverforalice.bobscompany.com) instead.
- Charlie signs up to Alice's business at [www.alice.sampledomain](http://www.alice.sampledomain). There are terms of service between Charlie and Alice. Charlie gives Alice his PII. Charlie only sees the sampledomain url unless he looks at the traffic headers with developer tools.

- Alice sends some of Charlie's PII to Bob's server, where they are processed.

Charlie may not even be able to know if Alice is using Bob or doing the computing herself if he isn't reading the legal terms Alice could switch between using Amazon AWS or Microsoft Azure or one of the other cloud companies or hosting things herself and still provide the same-looking website under the same URL.

So Alice is Charlie's first contact. Alice would probably be required to disclose in the fine print of her TOS that she is using a [data processor](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679#d1e3150-1-1), but Alice remains the data controller as long as Bob's server **does only what Alice tell it to do**.

Bob does have obligations under GDPR, but those are mostly towards the supervising authorities and towards Alice. Alice is required by GDPR to have a contract with Bob which assures the proper handling of personal data. Alice might even design things so that all data on Bob's servers is encrypted so Bob **cannot** answer any questions or requests.

---

Note that this Q&A sounds different from what came out in the comments in [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/63700/gdpr-does-it-give-the-right-to-unnecessarily-ask-to-be-removed-from-a-group) question by you. Are you really asking two different questions?

Comment: In this scenario Alice does not tell bob what to do an data is shared only when charlie chooses to share it .

Comment: @fewquestions, Charlie shares by klicking buttons on Alice's webpage, which happens to be hosted on Bob's computer?

Comment: Charlie clicks a button on which it is specified what data is processed by Bob . This button is located on sever or webpage of alice . alice sends personal data it has collected from charlie to bob . bob processes it in his own way in accordance with his published policy then returns a response to alice which is formated without altering meaning andg presented to charlie . Then data isdeleted by bob within ten minuites .

Comment: @fewquestions, Alice can still have a contract with Bob which makes Bob the data processor, or Charlie has to be presented by Bob with Bob's terms of service.

Comment: yes Bob declares the terms but data is retained by Alice .